# Rails 3.0.7 ActionMailer attachment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, actionmailer

I'm trying to attach a file to an outgoing email but the attachment size ends up being 1 byte. It doesn't matter what attachment I'm forwarding it always ends up in the email 1 byte in size (corrupt). Everything else looks ok to me.

The email information is pulled from an IMAP account and stored in the database for browsing purposes. Attachments are stored on the file system and it's file name stored as an associated record for the Email.

In the view there's an option to forward the email to another recipient. It worked in Rails 2.3.8 but for Rails 3 I've had to change the attachment part of the method so now it looks like...

```
def forward_email(email_id, from_address, to_address)
    @email = Email.find(email_id)
    @recipients = to_address
    @from = from_address
    @subject = @email.subject
    @sent_on = Time.now
    @body = @email.body + "\n\n"

    @email.attachments.each do |file|
      if File.exist?(file.full_path)
        attachment :filename => file.file_name, :body => File.read(file.full_path)
      else
        @body += "ATTACHMENT NOT FOUND: #{file.file_name}\n\n"
      end
    end
end
```

I've also tried it with...

```
attachments[file.file_name] = File.read(file.full_path)
```

and adding :mime_type and :content_type to no avail.

Any help would be a appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I did work with Nokogiri a lot. You can take me as a paid dev( I chrage very small amount). I saw [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922815/having-trouble-determining-if-element-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, someone from the rails team answered my question. The problem lies with adding body content (@body) other than the attachment inside the method. If you're going to attach files you have to use a view template.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried and worked for me

```
 attachments.each do |file|
      attachment :content_type => MIME::Types.type_for(file.path).first.content_type, :body => File.read(file.path) 
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file readable? Can you debug the issue by placing something like this?

```
logger.debug "File: #{file.full_path.inspect} : #{File.read(file.full_path).inspect[0..100]}"
```

Is there anything in your development.log?

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get in the log...

File: "/rails/jts/attachments_development/2011/2815/14035482661 (1 minute and 3 seconds) Voice Mail.wav" : "RIFFl\224\001\000WAVEfmt \024\000\000\0001\000\001\000@\037\000\000Y\006\000\000A\000\000\000\002\00


Other than this nothing of note appears in the dev log

Comment: If I do this...

attachments[file.file_name] = {:content => File.read(file.full_path)}

then I get a text version of the attachment at the bottom of the email but the email doesn't know it's an attachment. The email size looks right though