# Having trouble determining if element exists

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an xml document full of nested `item` nodes. In most cases, each `item` has a `name` element. I want to check if an `item` has a `name` element, and return a default name if one doesn't exist.

```
<item>
  <name>Item 1</name>
</item>
<item>
    <items>
        <item>
          <name>Child Item 1</name>
        </item>
        <item>
          <name>Child Item 2</name>
        </item>
    </items>
</item>
```

When I ask `node.at('name')` for the node with no `name` element, it picks the next one from the children further down the tree. In the case above, if I ask `at('name')` on the second `item`, I get `"Child Item 1"`.

Comment: Which is the second item in your xml? Which xml parsing library are you using? Is the result expected behavior?

Comment: Not sure how it got changed, but the subject of the post was originally "Nokogiri: having trouble determining if element exists".

Comment: @ChrisA. On this site we try to keep tags out of the title; sawa edited your question to better match accepted standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using `at()`, which can accept either a CSS selector or an XPath expression, and tries to guess which you gave it. In this case it thinks that `name` is a CSS selector, which is a descendant selector, selecting `name` elements anywhere below the current node.

Instead, you want to use an XPath expression to find only **child** `<name>` elements. You can do this either by making it clearly an XPath expression:

```
node.at('./name')
```

or you can do it by using the `at_xpath` method to be clear:

```
node.at_xpath('name')
```

Here's a simple working example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML '<r>
  <item id="a">
    <name>Item 1</name>
  </item>
  <item id="b">
      <items>
          <item id="c">
            <name>Child Item 1</name>
          </item>
          <item id="d">
            <name>Child Item 2</name>
          </item>
      </items>
  </item>
</r>'

doc.css('item').each do |item|
  name = item.at_xpath('name')
  name = name ? name.text : "DEFAULT"
  puts "#{item['id']} -- #{name}"
end

#=> a -- Item 1
#=> b -- DEFAULT
#=> c -- Child Item 1
#=> d -- Child Item 2
```